# ОБУЧИТЕ СВОЙ СОБСТВЕННЫЙ КЛАССИФИКАТОР OPENCV HAAR

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Помогите новичку с проблемой. Я обучаю модель OPENCV HAAR
на своих картинках. Надо выполнить команду `find ./positive_images -iname "*.jpg" > positives.txt`
при этом выскакивает ошибка. Скрин приложу может кто сталкивался??[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде как  `find ./positive_images -iname "*.jpg" > positives.txt`
Используется в linux, а на скриншоте у вас windows.

Comment: Можете помочь переделать?

Comment: В винде будет что-то типа `dir /b positive_images/*.jpg > positives.txt`

Comment: Спасибо!!Попробую

Comment: Недопустимый ключ: "*.jpg".